# One form with two image buttons is sending both values of the buttons when only one can be pressed

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to send data from a form and in this form there are 2 image buttons. One of the buttons saves the data while the other sends it to another form. The problem is that when I press either image button both "*saveDaTa*" and "*saveData*" values get sent.

these hidden inputs gets sent with either image button that I press.

```
<input type="hidden" name="saveData" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="sendData" value="3">
```

I checked what im getting with **var_dump** and both variables are being sent.

```
//var_dump($this->input->post(NULL, TRUE));
  'saveData' => string '2' (length=1)
  'sendData' => string '3' (length=1)

<td rowspan="2" align="center">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:document.forms['form1'].submit();">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/save.png" alt="Save Data" width="30" height="30" />
        <input type="hidden" name="saveData" value="2">
    </a>
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;Save  

 <!-- The user pressed the icon to send the data so it will now have to save that the user decided to do this in the database a Boolean in the database  
still the view. -->

</td>
<td rowspan="2" align="center">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:document.forms['form1'].submit();">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/save.png" alt="Send Data" width="30" height="30" />
        <input type="hidden" name="sendData" value="3">
    </a>
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;Send
</td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, when the form is sent, all the hidden inputs are sent as well.
You could do it simple:

```
<style>
.ibtn {
  border:none;
  padding:0;
}
.ibtn::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0
}
</style>

<form>
  <button class="ibtn" name="send" value="1"><img src="http://www4.dict.cc/img/but_speech.gif"></button>
  <button class="ibtn" name="send" value="2"><img src="http://www4.dict.cc/img/but_speech.gif"></button>
</form>
```

The other alternative is to separate two forms each with its own data.

Comment: I have two forms in one page. so how do I specify what form im sending with your answer